# Hovering only on Images not on files

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, hover

I am new to web design stuff, and this is my first question (sry , if any mistake)
Currently i am working on project, where i allow the users to upload document using telerik:RadAsyncUpload.

User can upload :as many as images ( jpg,jpef,png ) and files ( docx,doc,pdf).
TO display the uploaded files dynamically i am using asp:Repeater.

Here my question is that , how can i apply 'Hover' only on images uploaded by user i.e,
when i hover on image it should effect. where as when i hover on files of any type (pdf,docx,doc) hover should not apply.
This i want to do it by using Jquery. and i have idea i.e,

1.first get the uploaded files and store its extension in varibale
2.compare the type.
3.

```
if type == 'jpg | jpeg | png |
  hover
else
  should not hover (for type = 'doc|docx|pdf')
```

This is my idea but I am not getting how to start.

So any ideas and solution regarding this question please share with me.

Appreciate , if any one could help me.
Thx

Comment: can you give some code how you display your images and files?

Comment: Please share exact code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with telerik:RadAsyncUpload so i want to know if the images are displayed as an <img/> tag or is only the filename shown?

Answer (score 0):

if you share your code then things might get clear, but if image tags are used then this solution might be helpful.

```
  $('img').mouseover(function () {
            $('img').css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
        $('img').mouseout(function () {
            $('img').css('border', '0px solid red');
        });
```